# Displaying black screen after installing the app from App Store for iOS 7, working fine in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios7, installation, app-store

I have deployed my application to the App Store, and it has been verified successfully. Now, using iOS 6 iPhone devices if i am installing the application directly from the App Store then it is successfully installing on my device, but it is displaying black screen after installing in iOS 7 devices (Not installing). Can you please suggest me that where is my mistake? I am working on XCODE 5.0.2 and here below is some screenshots for your reference that i have set deployment info during submission.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I could install your app successfully from AppStore into my iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.1, but it’s showing a black screen when launching the app. You will need to check whether or not Launch images are set correctly.

Comment: Check out this sample code from Apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Icons/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @JoeyThanks... even i am getting the same black screen after installation. I am checking in my code.

Comment: @JoeyCan you please tell me what could be the issue, i am using Reachability for checking internet, is Reachability work for iOS7 ??

Comment: Sorry, your app, Navent, is working well in my device. It's just showing a black screen only first 1-2 secs when launching the app. You can see device logs in Organizer (Command + Shift + 2), if the device is connected by USB cable. That would help you out.

Comment: @JoeyThanks alot bro.. i got the problem.

Comment: if it's urgent, you may request to have Expedited App Review. Cheers! https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review